# Server-side processing with ajax source data

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I tried to submit dynamic data to jscript and render the data using php from api url, but how can I pass the pagination number to the datable jscript and letting php to define the pageindex dynamically?
I tried to pass the value into the function, it will totally reload the ajax table for me and stay back at page number 1 instead of page number 2.

the api returns:

```
{
    "data": [...],
    "pageindex": 1,
    "totalrecord": 708,
    "totalpage": 71
}
```

My Form jquery:

```
$('.form-filter form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const start = $('.form-filter [name=start]').val();
    const end = $('.form-filter [name=end]').val();
    const type = $('.form-filter [name=type]').val();
    const status = $('.form-filter [name=status]').val();
 
    if (this.checkValidity() !== false) {
        action_handle('fire_search');
        var datetime = timezone(start, end);
        paymentTable(datetime[0], datetime[1], type, status);
    }
});
```

The datatable jscript:

```
function paymentTable(from, to, type, status) {
    const paymentTable = $('#table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            type : "POST",
            url: "/api/somethinng/history",
            data: {"start": from, "end": to, "type": type, "status": status},
            dataSrc: function(json) {
                if(json == "no data") {
                    return [];
                } else {
                    return json.data;
                }
 
            }
        },
        responsive: {
            details: {
                renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
                    tableClass: 'ui display nowrap table-sm table-bordered'
                })
            }
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        deferRender: true,
        destroy: true,
        order: [[0,"desc"]],
        }
    });
 
    paymentTable.draw();
}
```

My PHP function to get the data from api:

```
public function api_history() {
    $raw = $this->balance_model->data_source([
        'type' => 1,
        'status' => 1,
        'fromdate' => '2020-10-01',
        'todate'=> '2020-10-05',
        'pageindex' => 1,
        'rowperpage' => 1000
    ]);
 
    if( $raw['code'] == 1 && $raw['data'] != [] ):
        asort($raw['data']);
        $data = [];
        foreach( $raw['data'] as $ph ):
            $row = [];
            $row[] = $ph['date'];
            $row[] = $ph['id'];
            $row[] = $ph['amount'];
            $data[] = $row;
        endforeach;
        echo json_encode([
            'data' => $data
            'draw' => (int)$_POST['draw'],
            'recordsTotal' => $raw['totalRecord'],
            'recordsFiltered' => $raw['totalRecord']
        ]);
    else:
        echo json_encode(['no data']);
    endif;
}
```